# Which one scales better?

Tags: database, database-design, mysql

I have to make a design decision with regards to fields in the database.

Given:

- `users table`

Problem:

Visually we have a check box that says:

`[*] check this box to not show this again`

Should this data(boolean) be saved in the `users` table in a column or in a new joint table that has the `user_id`?

Which one scales better? faster?

Comment: Just answered a very similar question a few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926802/to-share-a-table-or-not-share/2926823#2926823

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your users table, but generally the performance difference here with good indexing is negligible at almost any scale.

At most you should only be grabbing this kind of info once at login to set as a session var / cookie / etc.